# Check JSON Schema which is syntactically correct, but not semantically

Tags: node.js, json, jsonschema, ajv

I want to check the JSON schema itself which is syntactically correct, but not semantically .

e.g

```
{
      "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
      "$id": "http://example.com/root.json",
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "checked"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "checked": {
          "$id": "#/properties/checked",
          "type_invalid":"string"
        }
      }
    }
```

In the above example has **type_invalid** key which is incorrect it should be **type**. Is there any way to validate JSON schema itself?

for reference:I am using [ajv](https://ajv.js.org) to validate JSON against JSON schema.

Comment: There is no existing tooling to do this, although I highly expect it will be developed this year. The admin team were discussing it this week as something we want, and there may soon be people to work on it.

Comment: You COULD copy the existing meta-schema, and modify it to not allow additional properties, and then use that to validate your schemas.

Comment: @Relequestual Thanks for the solution, this worked for me!

Comment: I'll add this as an answer for you to accept.

Comment: That will be really helpful

Comment: but this will not giving me proper error that which properties is invalid(Error: schema is invalid: data.properties['checked'] should NOT have additional properties)

Comment: That (error output) depends on the library you use. For draft-7, there is no standard way to report errors. This has been defined in the upcoming release of draft-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could copy the existing meta-schema, and modify it to not allow additional properties, and then use that to validate your schemas.

Comment: but this will not giving me proper error that which properties is invalid(Error: schema is invalid: data.properties['checked'] should NOT have additional properties) , can you please suggest

Comment: the solution you have provided is not working draft_04 meta schema

Comment: The schema you provided has a $schema which identifies it as draft-7.

Comment: yes your correct. can we achieve same behaviour for draft_04,draft_06,draft_07 ?

Comment: The answer was for draft-7 schemas. If you have draft-4 schemas, your schemas may be very different.

Comment: Is there any solution for draft_04

Comment: The solution should be the same for draft-4, as the `additionalProperties` key word exists in both.